# Displaying some WebPart controls only to some user/groups

Tags: web-part, audience-targeting

I need to hide some elements of a webpart and only show them to some specific grups of users. How can I do this ? I think it could be done with an If or Switch block, using the name of the grup of users which should see this Webpart controls, but how can I do it? Can anyone give some guidance on how to reach this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design the ascx carefully, the portion you want to show/hide declare the part as runat="server", example -

```
<table>
  <tr id="trShowHide1" runat="server">
  //some content
  </tr>
  <tr id="trShowHide2" runat="server">
  //some content
  </tr>
</table>
```

and in CreateChildControls() event (or if you think any other event suits you based on your requirement, but i prefer CreateChildControls) get the current user (you can use SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser), by this point you will have one [SPUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser_members.aspx) object of current user, check the group and/or other attribute, you will need spUser.Groups attribute to check for groups current user is member of, now check for required group in [SPGroupCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroupcollection_members.aspx) object (spUser.Groups returns the group collection object), example

```
if(user is in "Group1")
{
  trShowHide1.Visible=true;
  trShowHide2.Visible=false;
}
else
{
  trShowHide1.Visible=false;
  trShowHide2.Visible=true;
}
```

you can pretty much construct your own code from the sample i guess

Comment: I woried that i'm made not good code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best option is to use the Security Trimming controls, as in http://fusionovation.com/post/2008/09/18/security-trimmed-controls-in-sharepoint.aspx

As you would immediately realize is they do not support SPGroups, so find here a solution doing exactly this http://www.dhirendrayadav.com/2011/08/extending-sharepoint-security-trimmed.html

I find it a much better option for long term,
C:>Marius