# How to make that every users has it own sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am doing a project where I want to make several users to have their own page.

User:guest1 has his own page in sharepoint
Users:guest2 has his own page in sharepoint

should i use site pages? or what should i do?

Comment: Please provide more detail. What does the page for a user do? What does it show? If you want the user to be able to edit the page, then you may want to look at MySites. If the page just shows content that relates to the user, you may get by with creating just one page and have the content filtered to pertain to the current user.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you have webparts that are geared around user groups. rather than a seperate page for each group of users. So the webpart will show/hide depending on the group.

Or

if you insist you can have a webpart that finds the group that the user is in and redirects to a page that only that group has access to.

either way you will need a webpart and groups that users are in. Creating a page is simple on the site. Just create a webpart page will be sufficent :) , if your looking for individual page for each user than the first option is best as each page will show the webpart or/and info that is related to that user on one page for all users :)

as examples

http://spwebparthide.codeplex.com/

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/dynamically-showhide-multiple-web-parts.aspx

[Displaying some WebPart controls only to some user/groups](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52302/displaying-some-webpart-controls-only-to-some-user-groups)

http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Display-Web-Part-Content-Based-on-User-Group-by-Extending-Security-Trimmed-Control-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx

from the examples above you can do what your looking for easily :)

Answer (score 0):

At central administration go to Web Applications. Select a web app and in the ribbon there will be  "Self-Service Site Creation". Then select the options however you want. If I understand your question right, it has to solve your problem.

Comment: @ali Sharepoint  i have two accounts to windows server when logging in and then go to sharepoint i want to display his profile only , and when logging in with the other user only show his profile , so i want to have it private so the first user can not se the others profile

Comment: i have two accounts to windows server when logging in and then go to sharepoint i want to display his profile only , and when logging in with the other user only show his profile , so i want to have it private so the first user can not se the others profile